# I am trying to add a proxy to my react client, but I am getting a 404 error

Tags: reactjs, proxy, axios

I created setupProxy.js file inside my src directory after installing http-proxy-middleware,

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api/', { target: 'http://localhost:3002' }));
};
```

Here is my App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/api/product/brands').then(response => {
      console.log(response);
  });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Store!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

I did this in my server directories package.json file to run client and server concurrently

```
"start": "node server/server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server/server.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev":"concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
```

Please help me with this as I am getting a 404 error

Comment: Are you using that proxy export in webpack config ??

Comment: No.. could you please help me with that?

Comment: Are you using create react app or webpack ??

Comment: create-react-app

Comment: You can add that in package.json itself. Check how to add proxy in create react app.

Comment: I added proxy as a string in package.json, I am still getting the same error

Comment: You want `/api/product/brands` to hit on `http://localhost:3002/api/product/brands` endpoint, right ?

Comment: Yes, I want it to work like that.

Comment: Try `http://localhost:3002/api/product/brands` in postman and see whether it's working. and CORS should be enabled for API server.

Comment: Its working perfectly in postman, and I have enabled CORS too

Comment: Then it should work. I have tried it. One more thing. in setupProxy.js try putting `http://localhost:3002/` instead of `http://localhost:3002`. In create react app docs they have that slash at end.

Comment: Initially, I gave http://localhost:3002/ I had no luck. after going through some resources, I changed it back to http://localhost:3002

Comment: It should be `app.use(proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }));` as create react app docs says.

Comment: Did you try putting '/' at the end ???

Comment: Yes, I tried that. No luck

Comment: I'm sorry man, I cannot help anymore without seeing the project itself.

Comment: Try `fetch('/api/product/brands').then(r => r.json()).then(r => console.log(r))` I expect the service returns a Json. Try the fetch call in browser console of your website. And see network tab. If it didn't work replace URL for the fetch call by `http://localhost:3002/api/product/brands`. and see if it's working.